# How can I process the content of a CSV file as Pipeline input in Powershell cmdlet

Tags: powershell, pipeline, powershell-cmdlet

I want to use a CSV file to feed the parameters of powershell cmdlet

```
Role, email, fname, lname
Admin, a@b.com, John, Smith
```

I want to process a cmdlet as follows:

```
import-csv myFile| mycmdlet | export-csv myresults
```

I also want to be able to call the cmdlet like this

```
mycmdlet -role x -email j@b.com -fname John -lname Smith
```

and see a result as an object like:

```
lname: "Smith"
fname: "John"
email: "j@b.com"
role: "X"
ResultData: "something else"
```

I didn't want to have to do this:

```
import-csv X.txt | foreach-object { mycmdlet -email $_.email }
```

In the powershell I wanted to do something line this:

```
function global:test-Pipeline{
param(  
[Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)][String[]]$role, 
[Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)][String[]]$email, 
[Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)][String[]]$fname, 
[Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)][String[]]$lname ) 

$result = new-object psobject

process {
   foreach($address in $email)
   {
       Do something with each role, email, fname lname
       Add output to $result
   }
}

End {
    return $result
}
```

}

I'm sure this must be possible, how do i do it? Can it be done without having to process the CSV in the cmdlet?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you almost have it right. Your parameters should not use `ValueFromPipeline` but should use `ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName`. They should be `[String]` but not `[String[]]`. The reason is that you are going to get a single set of parameters, corresponding to a single input object, in each "pass".

You also don't need the `End{}` block here it should all be done in `Process{}`.

```
function Test-Pipeline{
    param(  
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)][String]$role, 
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)][String]$email, 
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)][String]$fname, 
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)][String]$lname 
    ) 


    Process {
        New-Object PSObject -Property @{
            role = "~$role~"
            email = "mailto:$email"
            fname = [cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase($fname)
            lname = [cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase($lname)
        }    
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Import-Csv myData.csv | Test-Pipeline | Export-Csv tranformedData.csv -NoTypeInformation

Import-Csv myData.csv | Test-Pipeline -role "Override Role" | ConvertTo-Json
```

---

## What's going on?

`Import-Csv` gives you one object for every row in the CSV, and each object has a property for each column in the CSV.

When you pipe that into another command, including your function each individual object gets sent through one at a time.

You could accept the one object, and process its properties in the command.

What you have here, using `ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName`, looks at the input object, if there is one, and if it contains a property that matches the name of the parameter (or any of its aliases), then the value of that property will be bound to the parameter (unless you specified on calling; that would override the input value).

Since you want objects again as a result, you create a new object in the `Process` block, which will be passed out through the pipeline to the next command.

Comment: As I'm understanding pipeline more - I think what I want is for the pipeline to be a custom object and make sure that all the properties needed in the custom object are defined and present in the pipeline in an optimized way

Comment: @JamesMoore if that's the case it sounds like you want to define a class to describe this type. You can set your parameters to mandatory if they must all be present (and add validation attributes). Then instead of creating a PSObject you can create an object of your type to pass through instead. If you don't want your own class, you do most of that stuff anyway as it passes through.