# Pipeline record invalidation

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I want to chain cmdlets together in a pipeline starting with a `Import-Csv` file of NN records to process, at the end I want to write out a result file for all NN records and the accumulated results of processing.   Along the way I may want to add data to the pipeline that says don't process this record any further, but still pass it along in the pipeline.

I envisioned this looking like this:

```
Import-Csv input | step-1 -env DEV | step-2 | step-3 | Export-Csv result
```

Each cmdlet being written to pipe all `$_` properties for each record and keep them in the pipeline.

What's the best way to read some sort of "CanContinue" property and if it is false short circuit processing and just pass it along to the next cmdlet in the pipeline without processing?

Comment: What exactly do you expect us to tell you about the way 3 hypothetical cmdlets may or may not work?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you don't want this flag to be part of the resulting CSV. The way I see it you can use 2 similar approaches: add the flag to the object being processed before returning it, or wrap the object in another object (which contains the flag and another property that holds the original object).

For now I'm going to explore the first option where you add the property. I'm going to change it from a positive `CanContinue` to a negative, `DoNotProcess` so that its non-existence can coalesce to `$false` (do continue).

To do this, in each of your processing functions, just check the value of the `DoNotContinue` property. If it's `$true`, return the original object you received without additional processing.

If it's `$false`, you can do your processing and if the conditions are met that processing should stop, you force add the property with `$true`:

```
Process {
    # processing done
    $MyObj |
        Add-Member -NotePropertyName DoNotContinue -NotePropertyValue $true -Force -PassThru
}
```

All such commands can handle it this way.

Now when it comes to the end of the pipeline, you don't want this property written to the CSV. For that, strip it off with `Select-Object`:

```
Import-Csv input | 
    step-1 -env DEV | 
    step-2 | 
    step-3 | 
    Select-Object -Property * -ExcludeProperty DoNotContinue |
    Export-Csv result
```

#### Bonus:

[Refer back to my answer on another question of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53291894/3905079), and instead of manually checking for the property, define it as a parameter in your processing cmdlets with `[Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]` like so:

```
param(
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
    [Switch]
    $DoNotContinue
)
```

Why do that? Because you let PowerShell process the object for you and you only have to check the value of `$DoNotContinue`. It also allows you to override that value for a particular call.

(in this case, I'd rename it to `$DoNotProcess` or `$SkipProcessing` or something; remember you can also use `[Alias()]` if you want it to have multiple names)

Comment: This is what I thought I was going to have to do.  I like the generic switch DoNotProcess.  In a Begin/Process/End scenario would is there an easy way to add this exit logic?   Would you use try/Catch logic or something else?

Comment: @JamesMoore `In a Begin/Process/End scenario would is there an easy way to add this exit logic?` you would add this logic in the `Process` block always, since that's the block that gets each pipeline item. The logic is just `if ($MyObj.DoNotContinue) { return $MyObj }` and the rest does processing, then if conditions are met to stop processing, add the member as in my answer.